# Not able to get the logs on grafana loki

Tags: grafana-loki

- job_name: system
  static_configs:

  - targets:

    - localhost
      labels:
      job: varlogs
      **path**: /var/log/*log
- job_name: system
  static_configs:

  - targets:

    - localhost
      labels:
      job: varlogs
      **path**: /var/log/grafana/*log

I have configured config promtail.yml file and inserted the above code but the log/job name are not showing in the grafana